# Different time interval util.date and DAYS.between(Localtime)

Tags: java, time, java.util.date, localdate

Something doesn't seem right and i just dont know how I can fix it.

I want to know the difference in days between 2 dates. Now I implemented a function, which calculates the differences from milliseconds to days for util.date objects

```
public long calculateNumberOfDays(Date from, Date to) {
    return (to.getTime() - from.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);
}
```

My jUnit test told me, there was an error with this function, so I rewrote it using LocalDate and the ChronoUnit.DAYS.between function. It worked like a charm.

Wanting to know what the differences between those two functions were, I wrote this little test:

```
for(int numberDays = 1; numberDays<10; numberDays++){
        LocalDate fromLD = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate toLD = fromLD.plusDays(numberDays);
        Date fromD = Date.valueOf(fromLD);
        Date toD = Date.valueOf(toLD);
        long diffMS = toD.getTime() - fromD.getTime();
        double diffDays = diffMS/(1000*60*60*24);
        long numDaysDate = DAYS.between(fromLD, toLD);
        System.out.println(numberDays+" = "+diffDays+"/"+numDaysDate);
}
```

It resulted in the following output:

```
1 = 1.0/1
2 = 2.0/2
3 = 3.0/3
4 = 4.0/4
5 = 4.0/5
6 = 5.0/6
7 = 6.0/7
8 = 7.0/8
9 = 8.0/9
```

Can someone explain to me, how this is possible? (1-4 it works, 5-9 util.date has lost a day)

Comment: Looks like daylight saving time about to start....

Comment: I didn't know we are saving a whole day this year :P

Comment: I made it an answer, but integer (or long) divisions round down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates are hard. A java `Date` is a date and time, so when you set it to an actual date, it means midnight on that date.

Daylight savings time kicks in any day now (at least over here), so midnight on Monday will be 23 hours after midnight on Sunday.

Dividing integers rounds down, so 4 days and 23 hours is 4 days

Casting the result of an integer division to a double is too late; you need to cast either or both of the inputs:

```
double diffDays = diffMS/(1000*60*60*24);
```

4.0

```
double diffDays = diffMS/(1000.0*60*60*24);
```

4.958333...

Comment: You are right, thank you. I thought i had that covered by making diffDays a double value. When i parse diffMS to double and then divide, the correct double values are generated.

Comment: When I say dates are hard, I mean *ridiculously* hard to do date/time manipulation without hitting this kind of bug. There's a reason java 8 contains a third attempt (after java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar) to  provide the tools. You're lucky you tested this the week before DST.